# Cannot find view by id, after adding it programatically

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a method to programmatically add View elements like CheckBox, EditText.. this is my method for one.

```
private void addCheckBox(JSONObject element, boolean visible)
{
    CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox(context);

    checkbox.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    ));

    checkbox.setText(element.get("label").toString());      
    checkbox.setId(Math.abs(element.get("id").toString().hashCode()));

    if(!visible)
    {
        checkbox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    checkbox.setChecked(Boolean.getBoolean(element.get("value").toString()));

    layout.addView(checkbox);       
}
```

Now I have a second method where I have a group of elements that can be toggled by the checkbox.

```
private void addGroup(JSONObject element)
{       
    // Add toggle checkbox
    addCheckBox(element, true);

    // Get propery for the toggle checkbox
    int id = Math.abs(element.get("id").toString().hashCode());
    boolean value = Boolean.parseBoolean(element.get("value").toString());
    final CheckBox toggle = (CheckBox) context.findViewById(id);

    // Get rest of the fields
    JSONArray fields = (JSONArray) element.get("fields");
    final ArrayList<Integer> tags = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    // Add all fields to the layout
    for(int i = 0; i < fields.size(); i++)
    {
        // Append each field belonging to this group
        JSONObject field = (JSONObject) fields.get(i);
        String type = field.get("type").toString();         

        switch (type)
        {
            case "checkbox": 
                addCheckBox(element, value);
                tags.add(Math.abs(field.get("id").toString().hashCode()));
                break;
                ...
        }
    }

    // Set toggle action for group elements
    toggle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {               
            // Toggle element visibility depending on toggle checbox state
            View view = (View) context.findViewById(1718389591);
            Log.w("JSON", "E:" + view.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

However the line `Log.w("JSON", "E:" + view.toString());` a null pointer exception. When I first call `addCheckBox()` the UI element is created and added to the layout and I'm able to find it in the id value: `int id = Math.abs(element.get("id").toString().hashCode());` however even tho the elements were rendered on the screen they can never be found in the `onClick()` method.

Comment: Did you hard-code the ID into the layout XML as well? If not, then that ID you're trying to get might not be the same the next time you run it.

Comment: I did not hard-code it into layout. I call the .setId() method to set the element id before I add it to the layout. Next time I run it the ID's will be the same because they are hashCodes of string ids that wont change. The problem is the ids are accessible outside onClick and not inside it.

Comment: Can you show us your "onCreate" or "onCreateView"? Are you inflating the proper layout? The thing is, you can show the elements but you can't access them through the id, you must be trying to access the wrong layout.

Comment: @Akagami I have nothing special there the layout I'm populating I have a reference in this class I even tried `layout.findViewById(..);`  But it did not work. What bugs me is why it finds `int id` and then `CheckBox toggle` and wont find others ?

Comment: You have to change `addCheckBox(element, value);` to `addCheckBox(field, value);` Otherwise they all get the same Id as the first one..
 ` 
 `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change `addCheckBox(element, value);` to `addCheckBox(field, value);` Otherwise they all get the same Id as the first one..